# R summary command doesn't produce summary statistics

Tags: r, lm, summary, plm

The `summary(dataframe1)` command gives me summary statistics of that data frame like max, min and number of NA. Similarly, `summary(dataframe1$column1)` gives me summary statistics for that specific variable within the data frame (one of its columns).

That works well until I run a few regressions with lm and plm and whenever I try to get some summary statistics of a column within the data frame dataframe1 via `summary(dataframe1$column1)`. I get as output "total sum of squares", "id" and "time".

Why does this happen? dataframe1 is not the name of my regression model but I do use dataframe1 as the data source of such regression models. How can I force the summary command to give me the summary statistics of dataframe1 again (i.e. max, min, number of NA etc)? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear without an actual example, but perhaps summary(dataframe1) is summarizing a dataframe. After you call lm() on the dataframe - the result is a list. So your are now summarizing that list . According to documentation the function invokes particular methods which depend on the class of the first argument.

Example from lm() documentation

```
library(stats)

ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)

#summary of dataframe
weightDataFrame <- data.frame(weight)
summary(weightDataFrame)

#summary of list
model <- lm(weight ~ group)
summary(model)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with plm version 2.6-1 in which the summary printout for pseries was extended to contain the summary of the base class as well. Here is an example:

```
library(plm) # version 2.6-1
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")

summary(Grunfeld$inv)
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>    0.93   33.56   57.48  145.96  138.04 1486.70

pGrunfeld <- pdata.frame(Grunfeld)
summary(pGrunfeld$inv) # pseries
#> total sum of squares: 9359944 
#>         id       time 
#> 0.76021734 0.06716957 
#> 
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>    0.93   33.56   57.48  145.96  138.04 1486.70
```